# Removing token beginning with backslash in python

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to remove all those token which are beginning with backslash. Below is my code and is not removing the tokens. Also how can I do this using regular expression?

```
tokens = [u'#hamandcheesecroissant', u'\u1026',u'#whoopwhoop', u'\u2026', u'jose', u'mourinho', u'refusing', u'acknowledge', u'lost']
new_tokens = []
for token in tokens:
  if token.startswith('\\'):
   new_tokens.append(token)
```

Comment: What are the contents of `tokens`?

Comment: in Python you shouldn't remove elements from list if you use this list in `for` - because `remove()` "move left" all elements and next loop can skip next element. Better create new list with elements which you want to keep.

Comment: `\u` doesn't exist in text - it is only method to put unicode char in text. So you doesn't have text with \ - `u'\u1026'` - but single char  `ဦ`

Comment: BTW: `u'\u1026'` is single char so to remove it use rather `len(token) != 1`

Comment: You can check `token.startswith('#')` to keep only tags.

Comment: @furas token list also has other strings like for e.g [u'westport', u'house', u'champagne', u'west', u'gowran', u'central', u'bank', u'\u2026']. I have updated my question again.

Comment: then use `len(token) != 1` because `u'\u1026'` and `u'\u2026'` are single chars (`ဦ` and `…`)

Answer (score 1):

`u'\u1026'` is a unicode string with a single character. The string does not have an actual backslash character. I suggest that you do some research on the `\u` syntax in Python strings.

Answer (score 0):

When Unicode characters are encoded, they taken up 2 or more bytes. So one way to figure out if a string contains Unicode characters is to compare the lengths:

```
>>> tokens = [u'#hamandcheesecroissant', u'\u1026',u'#whoopwhoop', u'\u2026', u'jose', u'mourinho', u'refusing', u'acknowledge', u'lost']
>>> [t for t in tokens if (len(t)==len(t.encode()))]
['#hamandcheesecroissant', '#whoopwhoop', 'jose', 'mourinho', 'refusing', 'acknowledge', 'lost']
```

You can modify the logic above to filter single-character Unicode strings.